# Torch, how to get a tensor of loss values during batch optimization

Tags: lua, neural-network, deep-learning, torch, loss

I am training a network with batch optimization over my training set, and I would like to get a loss vector containing the loss of each of my training examples.

More specifically I am using images (of size `3x64x64`) in a batch of size 64. Therefore my input is a tensor of size `64x3x64x64`.

During training when I write

```
output = net:forward(input)
loss = criterion:forward(input, target)
```

`loss` is a number, but I would like to get a tensor (of size 64) with one entry per image in my batch, corresponding to the loss value of this precise image.

Is there a way to do that *without looping* on the first dimension of my input tensor?

Answer (score 0):

The forward method calls another method, the `updateOutput` method which can be overwritten. 
For eg., in case of [MSECriterion()](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/MSECriterion.lua), you can change the method by commenting the call to the `THNN` library and write on your own how you want the criterion to function, i.e., do a normal element wise subtraction and then square(again element wise) and divide by the total number of data points(again element wise); then return the output as a tensor.

You will also need to recompile the nn package once you have changed this using `luarocks make rocks/[the scm file in the folder]` after navigating to the nn folder.

Comment: yes sure it is always possible to write a new method, I am aware of that :) I  just hoped it had been done previously, but it seems there is no option in the criterion functions to do that without rewriting them...